# swift - Animate SlideIn and SlideOut from left handSide

Tags: swift

How to SlideIn and SlideOut the menu from left hand side in swift?
The following code shows the menu on the left hand side but when the slideIn occurs quickly and it doesn't actually show the menu comes from left hand side. Also, The slideOut close the menu from right side instead of left side.

Here is my code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1

            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
            self.collectionView.frame.width - 10, height: 
            self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }, completion: nil)
```

and also for slideOut

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }
    }) { (completed: Bool)
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Slide in
self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: -(window.frame.width), y: 0, width: window.frame.width-50, height: window.frame.height)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.blackView.alpha = 1

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.width-50, height: window.frame.height)
}, completion: nil)

//Slide out
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.blackView.alpha = 0
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: -(window.frame.width), y: 0, width: window.frame.width-50, height: window.frame.height)
    }
}, completion: nil)
```